# ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "execution_date" of relation "task_fail" does not exist

Tags: python, database, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to run a DAG in airflow to ingest a dataset to google cloud storage.
This is the DAG script:

```
import os

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from google.cloud import storage
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID")
BUCKET = os.environ.get("GCP_GCS_BUCKET")

dataset_file = "yellow_tripdata_2021-01.parquet"
dataset_url = f"https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/{dataset_file}"
path_to_local_home = os.environ.get("AIRFLOW_HOME", "/opt/airflow/")
BIGQUERY_DATASET = os.environ.get("BIGQUERY_DATASET", 'trips_data_all')



# NOTE: takes 20 mins, at an upload speed of 800kbps. Faster if your internet has a better upload speed
def upload_to_gcs(bucket, object_name, local_file):
    """
    Ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python
    :param bucket: GCS bucket name
    :param object_name: target path & file-name
    :param local_file: source path & file-name
    :return:
    """
    # WORKAROUND to prevent timeout for files > 6 MB on 800 kbps upload speed.
    # (Ref: https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/74)
    storage.blob._MAX_MULTIPART_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024  # 5 MB
    storage.blob._DEFAULT_CHUNKSIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024  # 5 MB
    # End of Workaround

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket)

    blob = bucket.blob(object_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)


default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": days_ago(1),
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "retries": 1,
}

# NOTE: DAG declaration - using a Context Manager (an implicit way)
with DAG(
    dag_id="data_ingestion_gcs_dag",
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    tags=['dtc-de'],
) as dag:

    download_dataset_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="download_dataset_task",
        bash_command=f"curl -sSL {dataset_url} > {path_to_local_home}/{dataset_file}"
    )


    local_to_gcs_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="local_to_gcs_task",
        python_callable=upload_to_gcs,
        op_kwargs={
            "bucket": BUCKET,
            "object_name": f"raw/{dataset_file}",
            "local_file": f"{path_to_local_home}/{dataset_file}",
        },
    )

    bigquery_external_table_task = BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator(
        task_id="bigquery_external_table_task",
        table_resource={
            "tableReference": {
                "projectId": PROJECT_ID,
                "datasetId": BIGQUERY_DATASET,
                "tableId": "external_table",
            },
            "externalDataConfiguration": {
                "sourceFormat": "PARQUET",
                "sourceUris": [f"gs://{BUCKET}/raw/{dataset_file}"],
            },
        },
    )

    download_dataset_task >> local_to_gcs_task >> bigquery_external_table_task
```

When I try to trigger it, it gets stuck on running and I always get this log:

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/data_ingestion_gcs_dag/download_dataset_task/2022-09-28T11:15:38.340982+00:00/2.log
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1032} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: data_ingestion_gcs_dag.download_dataset_task manual__2022-09-28T11:15:38.340982+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1032} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: data_ingestion_gcs_dag.download_dataset_task manual__2022-09-28T11:15:38.340982+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1238} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1239} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 3
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1240} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1259} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): download_dataset_task> on 2022-09-28 11:15:38.340982+00:00
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 2532 to run task
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'data_ingestion_gcs_dag', 'download_dataset_task', 'manual__2022-09-28T11:15:38.340982+00:00', '--job-id', '33', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/data_ingestion_gcs_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpxin03j36', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmp1zqihjcz']
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 33: Subtask download_dataset_task
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: data_ingestion_gcs_dag.download_dataset_task manual__2022-09-28T11:15:38.340982+00:00 [running]> on host b46ac29d5228
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1700} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column xcom.execution_date does not exist
LINE 1: ...g' AND xcom.task_id = 'download_dataset_task' AND xcom.execu...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1329, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1415, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    self.clear_xcom_data()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 792, in clear_xcom_data
    session=session,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 323, in clear
    return query.delete()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3926, in delete
    delete_op.exec_()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1697, in exec_
    self._do_exec()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1930, in _do_exec
    self._execute_stmt(delete_stmt)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1702, in _execute_stmt
    self.result = self.query._execute_crud(stmt, self.mapper)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3568, in _execute_crud
    return conn.execute(stmt, self._params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column xcom.execution_date does not exist
LINE 1: ...g' AND xcom.task_id = 'download_dataset_task' AND xcom.execu...
                                                             ^

[SQL: DELETE FROM xcom WHERE xcom.dag_id = %(dag_id_1)s AND xcom.task_id = %(task_id_1)s AND xcom.execution_date = %(execution_date_1)s]
[parameters: {'dag_id_1': 'data_ingestion_gcs_dag', 'task_id_1': 'download_dataset_task', 'execution_date_1': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 11, 15, 38, 340982, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1277} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=data_ingestion_gcs_dag, task_id=download_dataset_task, execution_date=20220928T111538, start_date=20220928T113129, end_date=20220928T113129
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:92} ERROR - Failed to execute job 33 for task download_dataset_task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column xcom.execution_date does not exist
LINE 1: ...g' AND xcom.task_id = 'download_dataset_task' AND xcom.execu...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1329, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1415, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    self.clear_xcom_data()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 792, in clear_xcom_data
    session=session,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/xcom.py", line 323, in clear
    return query.delete()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3926, in delete
    delete_op.exec_()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1697, in exec_
    self._do_exec()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1930, in _do_exec
    self._execute_stmt(delete_stmt)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1702, in _execute_stmt
    self.result = self.query._execute_crud(stmt, self.mapper)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3568, in _execute_crud
    return conn.execute(stmt, self._params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column xcom.execution_date does not exist
LINE 1: ...g' AND xcom.task_id = 'download_dataset_task' AND xcom.execu...
                                                             ^

[SQL: DELETE FROM xcom WHERE xcom.dag_id = %(dag_id_1)s AND xcom.task_id = %(task_id_1)s AND xcom.execution_date = %(execution_date_1)s]
[parameters: {'dag_id_1': 'data_ingestion_gcs_dag', 'task_id_1': 'download_dataset_task', 'execution_date_1': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 11, 15, 38, 340982, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "execution_date" of relation "task_fail" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO task_fail (task_id, dag_id, execution_date, star...
                                                ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 298, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 184, in _run_raw_task
    error_file=args.error_file,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1386, in _run_raw_task
    self.handle_failure(e, test_mode, error_file=error_file, session=session)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1755, in handle_failure
    session.flush()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2540, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2682, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2642, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
    uow,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1136, in _emit_insert_statements
    statement, params
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "execution_date" of relation "task_fail" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO task_fail (task_id, dag_id, execution_date, star...
                                                ^

[SQL: INSERT INTO task_fail (task_id, dag_id, execution_date, start_date, end_date, duration) VALUES (%(task_id)s, %(dag_id)s, %(execution_date)s, %(start_date)s, %(end_date)s, %(duration)s) RETURNING task_fail.id]
[parameters: {'task_id': 'download_dataset_task', 'dag_id': 'data_ingestion_gcs_dag', 'execution_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 11, 15, 38, 340982, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 11, 31, 29, 633052, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'end_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 28, 11, 31, 29, 734536, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'duration': 0}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-09-28, 11:31:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1277} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=data_ingestion_gcs_dag, task_id=download_dataset_task, execution_date=20220928T111538, start_date=20220928T113129, end_date=20220928T113129
```

I've tried everything I could think of. I rebuilt airflow image using docker. I tried to edit the code to no avail. I always get this error.
BTW: I'm using the latest version of airflow.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was with airflow itself. I reinstalled using a simpler image without ariflow-init and put the environment variables in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be the result of the [database migrations](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/migrations-ref.html) not being run on the Airflow database.  This is definitely an issue with Airflow, as `task_fail` is the database table it uses to keep track of failed tasks.  Airflow version 1.x has a column called `execution_date` while, per revision id `7b2661a43ba3`, Airflow 2.2.x+ does not.

If you run into this again, you can try to run this with the CLI:

```
airflow db upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an updated version of the Dockerfile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).