# Airflow failed to get task instance

Tags: airflow, instance, execution-time, airflow-xcom

i have tried to run a simple task using airflow bash operator but keep getting stuck on my DAG never stop running, it stays like green forever without success or fail, when i check the logs i see something like this. Thanks in advance for your time and answers

```
**`your text`**airflow-scheduler_1  | [SQL: INSERT INTO task_fail (task_id, dag_id, execution_date, start_date, end_date, duration) VALUES (%(task_id)s, %(dag_id)s, %(execution_date)s, %(start_date)s, %(end_date)s, %(duration)s) RETURNING task_fail.id]
airflow-scheduler_1  | [parameters: {'task_id': 'first_task', 'dag_id': 'LocalInjestionDag', 'execution_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 8, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 23, 3, 35, 27, 332954, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'end_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 23, 3, 35, 27, 710572, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), 'duration': 0}]

postgres_1           | 2023-01-23 03:55:59.712 UTC [4336] ERROR:  column "execution_date" of relation "task_fail" does not exist at character 41"""
```

I have tried with execution_datetime , using xcom_push and creating functions with xcom and changing to python operator but everything still fall back to same error

Comment: Can you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73881159/programmingerror-psycopg2-errors-undefinedcolumn-column-execution-date-of-r ? the problem was with Airflow itself, can you try to reset the db or reinstall Airflow?

Comment: Thank you Hussein, i really appreciate your feedback and answer to my question, i will surely do what you said.